# HTTP Web Server on XPage for Bluemix

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I have deployed an Xpage in Bluemix and binded a no-sql xpage database to the app. Anonymous has manager access to both the database. Anyone can create a document but once created cannot open the he document. It gives the following error:

> Error 500
>
> HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please activate the default error page setting in the XSP settings to display the stack trace and post the code of your page/link that causes the error. Otherwise no one could ever help you properly.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting

**Unable to get document page name for 892D819ECE966BF486257E9B0037DB01**
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unable to get document page name for 892D819ECE966BF486257E9B0037DB01

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I can read that you are just having an XPage to create a document. When you open it you reference it only by the UNID and not calling the .xsp page with the UNID like

```
doc.xsp?docid=892D819ECE966BF486257E9B0037DB01&action=openDocument
```

Either you calculate the opening link this way OR you create a corresponding form and set it's properties to open the XPage when accessed through the browser.
But as I said: without any code sample this is just a guess.

Comment: I am trying to open the document from a data view and the document and form is in different database and the xpages are in different database so cannot set open with xpage in the document.

Comment: Then you have to modify the URL and the datasource that is used in the XPage. The datasource must point to the database where your data is stored. Maybe you should start with the Demo app you find in the Bluemix documentation to see how to do it.

Comment: This is the relevant documentation that may help: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/XPagesNoSQLDatabase/index.html#xpservice_portexisting
See part 3 "Replace all data references in the design application."

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a definition to your XPages application in your XSP properties file:

```
xsp.domino.form.xpage.<NAME OF THE FORM>=<NAME OF YOUR XPAGE>
```

f.e.
Form="foo", XPage="bar"

```
xsp.domino.form.xpage.foo=bar.xsp
```

Alternativly, create your own `VirtualPageTransformer`: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1028

Comment: Shouldn't it be the XSP properties instead of faces-config?

Comment: @OliverBusse: Ups, da hast Du recht.